# Ajuda em cURL, reenviando o formulário

Tags: php, libcurl

estou tendo uma dúvida quanto ao processo de envio do formulário com **CAPTCHA**, estou tentando pegar dados direto do ***DENATRAN***, vamos entendo o que eu fiz.

1. Pegar a informação: Eu fiz um script em cUrl junto com o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
   para conseguir puxar as informações da página do [DENATRAN](http://denatran.serpro.gov.br/certificado/veiculo.asp).
2. Processar o **CAPTCHA**: eu consigo fazer a automação da verificação do código do **CAPTCHA** que está presente no formulário.

Minha dúvida agora é: Como eu posso enviar ou reenviar o que eu peguei de lá, pois existe um token no formulário, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda, eu sei que o formulário passa 6 parâmetros (hdnIntRC, hdnMsg, txtCPFCNPJ, txtCodRenavam, txtToken_captcha_serpro_gov_br, txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br).

Comment: Hum...Intersting... https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_(chave_eletr%C3%B4nica)

Comment: Caro @MagicHat, estou tentando fazer o envio de um formulário, ou seja, esse tipo de token não se aplica.

Comment: qual a dificuldade? posta a parte onde o code emperra...

Comment: Bom a dificuldade está bem descrita no meu post, não estou conseguindo postar os dados.

Comment: Hummm...Essa descrição pro meu compiler pessoal está em uma camada mais alta... Mas quem sabe... Aparece alguém que possa interpretar de acordo a leitura...